# Can't override product status in Django Mezzanine admin

Tags: django, overriding, customization, mezzanine

Hi I've been trying to override Django Mezzanine's product status field (Draft/ Published) and add a new option (Draft/Published/Research) in admin but no luck. I'm a total newbie at Django trying to start a new project on Django instead of Wordpress, so please see with my low knowledge on django's structure.

Here's my code:

cart/cart/apps/mezzanine/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from mezzanine.core.models import Slugged, MetaData, TimeStamped

CONTENT_STATUS_DRAFT = 1
CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED = 2
CONTENT_STATUS_RESEARCH = 3

CONTENT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (CONTENT_STATUS_DRAFT, _("Draft")),
    (CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED, _("Published")),
    (CONTENT_STATUS_RESEARCH, _("Research")),
)


class Displayable(Slugged, MetaData, TimeStamped):

status = models.IntegerField(_("Status"),
    choices=CONTENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=CONTENT_STATUS_RESEARCH,
    help_text=_("With Draft chosen, will only be shown for admin users "
        "on the site."))

publish_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Published from"),
    help_text=_("With Published chosen, won't be shown until this time"),
    blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)


Displayable.default=CONTENT_STATUS_RESEARCH 
Displayable.choices=CONTENT_STATUS_CHOICES
```

cart/cart/apps/mezzanine/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from mezzanine.conf import settings
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from cart.apps.mezzanine.models import Displayable
from mezzanine.core.admin import BaseTranslationModelAdmin



class DisplayableAdminForm(ModelForm):

    def clean_content(form):
        status = form.cleaned_data.get("status")
        content = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        if status == CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED and not content:
            raise ValidationError(_("This field is required if status "
                                "is set to published."))
        return content




class DisplayableAdmin(BaseTranslationModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title", "status", "admin_link")
    list_display_links = ("title",)
    list_editable = ("status",)
    list_filter = ("status", "keywords__keyword")

    date_hierarchy = None if settings.USE_MODELTRANSLATION else "publish_date"
    radio_fields = {"status": admin.HORIZONTAL}
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            "fields": ["title", "status", ("publish_date", "expiry_date")],
        }),
    (_("Meta data"), {
        "fields": ["_meta_title", "slug",
                   ("description", "gen_description"),
                    "keywords", "in_sitemap"],
        "classes": ("collapse-closed",)
    }),
)
form = DisplayableAdminForm




admin.site.register(Displayable, DisplayableAdmin)
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "cartridge.shop",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    "cart.apps.mezzanine",
    "mezzanine.core",

)
```

versions:

Mezzanine 4.2.3
Django 1.10.8
Python 2.7.6
SQLite 3.8.2

There are no errors and the dev server loads fine. What step am I missing? Do I need to configure app.py for Mezzanine? Thanks for any help on this.